# Use type of object in HQL where clause

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, hql

In my domain model I have an abstract class CommunicationChannelSpecification, which has child classes like FTPChannelSpecification, EMailChannelSpecification and WebserviceChannelSpecification. Now I want to create an HQL query which contains a where clause that narrows down the result to certain types of channel specifications. E.g. (in plain English) select all CommunicationChannelSpecifications that whose types occur in the set {FTPChannelSpecification, WebserviceChannelSpecification}.

How can this be achieved in HQL? I'm using NHibernate 2.0.1 and a table per subclass inheritance mapping strategy...

Thanks!

Pascal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not positive in NHibernate, but in Hibernate, there are two special properties that are always referenced id and class. So, for your particular case, I'd do

```
from CommunicationChannelSpecifications spec where spec.class in (?)
```

Comment: nice answer, but what if we want to do that in an update (hql). I mean update Entity where class = com.pa.SubEntity?

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate supports the same syntax as Hibernate in this case.  See [here](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryhql-where) for an example.